# Editing word table from access, Error 462

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I'm using Access to edit some tables in Word, the code opens the document, adds X amount of rows and inserts data:

```
On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear
Set appword = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If appword Is Nothing Then
Set appword = New Word.Application
appword.Visible = True

End If
appword.Visible = True
Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(wordName, , False)

Set objTable = doc.Tables(1)
objTable.Rows(3).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow (aRows)
```

This is pretty much it, there's also some code there to insert data into various columns. The problem is however, the first time I run this code it Works like a charm, adds the right amount of rows and inserts data. It reaches the end of the codeblock and doesn't hang.

However, when I try to run the code again, it crashes at the:

```
Selection.InsertRowsBelow (aRows)
```

And throws the 462 Error
I've done some Reading and I kind of understand whats happening but I'm at a loss as to how to correct it.
(aRows here is an integer, value is checked to be correct).

Comment: I'm guessing: close the document and set appword to Nothing at the bottom of your logic.

Comment: Yes that was my first Instinct aswell, however it the problem stil persists. It does work if I reset the Project though, does this give you any Clues?

Comment: Be sure to do a `doc.Close`. What is `aRows`?

Comment: What is error 462?

Comment: Error 462 is : "The Remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". I need to make sue all Methods and Properties are qualified With the appropriate Object variable, but im slightly at a loss as to how to accomplish that.

Comment: Try adding these at the end: `appword.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone    doc.Close True
    appword.Quit`

Comment: Also if any of your variables is not local, set all word references to nothing: `appword`, `doc`, **and also** `objTable`. You might also try working without  `Select` and `Selection`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing:

```
Selection.InsertRowsBelow(<Integer>)
```

to

```
doc.ActiveDocument.Selection.InsertRowsBelow(<Integer>)
```